# Create Gtk toolbar with buttons and text in PyGobject

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

I found a couple of tutorials (PyGTK) that use this code:

```
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    [...]

    self.toolbar = Gtk.Toolbar()
    self.toolbar.set_style(Gtk.TOOLBAR_BOTH)

    [...]
```

but using Python3 and GTK3 (PyGobject) I get the message:

**AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'TOOLBAR_BOTH'**

Does anyone know how to handle this in PyGobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `Gtk.ToolbarStyle.BOTH`; to convert a C constant to Python like `GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH` which is a member of the `GtkToolbarStyle` enum, it's *(module name)*.*(enum name without module name)*.*(constant name without enum prefix)*.